# C#: syntax error at token '-' in:IL_0029: ldc.r8-inf when building from source

Tags: c#, build, buildconfiguration, rainmeter

I am trying to contribute to an [open source project](https://github.com/tjhrulz/WebNowPlaying) open source project. I've never worked with C# before, so I am not sure exactly how to write this out, but, here is what I've done so far.

I downloaded Visual Studio and some workloads, then forked and cloned the repo, and made a new project with the repo's .sln file. The project requires some API keys, so I filled those in, and then tried building.

I get the following error:

```
error : syntax error at token '-' in:     IL_0029:  ldc.r8     -inf
```

Google hasn't helped. I found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/545431/ildasmexe-regression-with-infinum-floating-point-v.html), but have no idea what it means.

Comment: They are using ILMerge... Might be coming from that.

Comment: I noticed the ILMergeOrder.txt is empty and that it can be filled in,but I am not sure what exactly to fill it in with. I tried filling in with some of the .ilmerge files in obj\x64\debug, but I still get the same error

Comment: You have to ask the project I think. But if that whole thing is just for you, you can remove ILMerge. It just there to have one merged DLL or EXE at the end. It’s not necessary for the function.